# Canvas Array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

Canvas Array object

I am new here, I am trying to read an Error popup message which is inside the canvas
I have defined the Canvas object and I am able to fetch the Canvas but not able to fetch the value from the Text attribute (highlighted),
Please guide me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmrAu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1oJ0.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.